# Django : This field is required on POST request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serializer which outputs the Report and also the User information.
My task is accomplished by this serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    latitude = serializers.CharField()
    longitude = serializers.CharField()
    city = serializers.IntegerField()
    type = serializers.IntegerField()

    # We have created a field which returns a value from get_marker_icon_url
    marker_icon = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_marker_icon_url')
    status_str = serializers.SerializerMethodField('convert_status_toStr')
    type_str = serializers.SerializerMethodField('convert_type_toStr')
    status_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_status_color')
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('random_likes')

    user = ReportUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Reports
        fields = [
            'user',
            'id', 
            'type',
            'city',
            'latitude', 
            'longitude',
            'likes', 
            'type_str', 
            'status_str', 
            'status_color', 
            'attached_message', 
            'marker_icon', 
            'attached_photo',
            'date_created'
        ]
...
```

With this code my serializer returns a response like this:

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "3nematix",
            "profile_pic": "http://192.168.0.29:8000/frontend/static/frontend/images/reports/user_profile_pic.jpg",
            "verified": false
        },
        "id": 1,
        "type": 9,
        "city": 0,
        "latitude": "6.5123333",
        "longitude": "51.512586",
        "likes": 27,
        "type_str": "OTHER",
        "status_str": "PENDING",
        "status_color": "orange",
        "attached_message": "test",
        "marker_icon": "OTHER",
        "attached_photo": "http://192.168.0.29:8000/frontend/static/frontend/images/reports/user_profile_pic_VRjIYTs.jpg",
        "date_created": "2020-10-21T23:19:06.899302Z"
    },
    ......
]
```

And this is exactly what I need, but the problem is that when I'm trying to create a new object by a POST request, I get this response:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

If I would remove `'user'` from Meta and `user = ReportUserSerializer()` from the `ReportSerializer` class, then I can create a new object, but when I wish to get the Reports I with the Users information I need to add these two again, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to fill the user field yourself before calling save.**

Here's the easy way:

```
class YourView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Or slightly differently:

```
class YourView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.validated_data['user'] = self.request.user
        return super().perform_create(serializer)
```